# How To Get Started With Hand Cycling

Tags: product-rec, advice, handcycle

I sustained a knee injury about a year ago and it's looking like I won't be biking anytime soon.  I thought that a good alternative would be to get into hand cycling.  I am having a hard time finding information on purchasing a hand bike.

To give information about my situation:  I am still able to walk.  So, I need a bike that would work for someone with legs.  When I was able to cycle, I was biking 100 to 150 miles per week (occasionally more) and averaging about 18 mph.  My rides would range from 20 miles up to a century.  I see no reason why I wouldn't get into hand cycling enough to want to get up to that level again.  Does anyone have any advice, help, or resources to offer to help me find a proper bike?  Thanks.

Comment: other than searching for handcycles, no. Be aware that you have much less power in your arms, so you're probably looking at 30-40 miles/week at 10mph, on a bike that costs $3000-$5000.

Comment: There are also wheelchairs.

Comment: I would suggest that you look around for some folks who use handcycles and seek their advice.  In our community of about 80,000 souls there are several handcycle riders -- two that I know and several others they know & have told me about.  I'm sure most would be glad to help you or to direct you to someone who would.

Comment: I created a [tag:handcycle] tag; we've had a few questions about them by now.

Comment: There are people with a [single leg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40dgntexQ3A) (due to amputation) that use regular bikes. It might be hard to resist the urge to push with the damaged leg, but with some practice it might not be too bad. Talk to your doctor/physiotherapist about it.  It would definitely be cheaper than getting a handcycle, and even with the only the power of a single leg, you'd be able to go faster.

Comment: Have you seen the Dual Drive Total Fitness Bike? I saw this the other day on kickstarter. It seems it would allow you to use hands for front wheel drive, as well as legs if your knee was feeling up to it on rear wheel drive. [https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1394897519/dual-drive-total-fitness-bike](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1394897519/dual-drive-total-fitness-bike) Unfortunately, it is still in "backing" stages. But maybe something to look for if you haven't found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to edit this answer to add more resources.

Hand cycling is a [Paralympic sport](http://www.paralympic.org/cycling), administered by the [UCI](http://www.uci.ch/para-cycling/). There are links at the bottom of the UCI page for all world regions.

Here is a link for [Disabled Sports USA](http://www.disabledsportsusa.org/handcycling/), describing different kinds of bikes and listing local chapters and a bunch of useful links.

The [United States Handcycle Federation](http://www.ushf.org/) seems to be mainly about competition.

Cycling Australia has a [Para-Cycling page](http://www.cycling.org.au/Para-Cycling), there is the Queensland [Sporting Wheelies and Disabled Association](http://www.sportingwheelies.org.au/our-services/sport/sports-a-z/cyclinghandcycling), and [Wheelchair Sport NSW](http://wsnsw.org.au/sports/handcycling/). I'm sure there are bodies in each state, but a quick search didn't locate them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with handcycles, however you can get some really good electric assist bikes these days. Not sure what the situation is with your knee, however if you are able to pedal to some degree this might be the thing to help you where your knees would typically feel the strain like on the hills.

I am currently considering a dutch cargo bike with electric assist, as the hills around my place are too much to manage 20kg bike, plus to toddlers and a bunch of groceries. From my limited research they'd get you about 15-20 miles at about 18mph, so not the full century, however it might be enough to let you do the recreational ride